# Is there a way to detect which email changed when using mailcore 2?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mailcore2

I have built a small email client using mailcore and I need to know if something changed, even if I've already known about that email's UID and have 'seen' it. For example, if someone flags an email that was received 5 days ago, I need to be able to detect this without having to pull every email and see which one changed in comparison to the one I have recorded locally.

Currently I'm polling and then looking through every email in the Inbox but that doesn't look right, as it'll have huge performance implications.

Comment: You have to pull every emails.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I went through the offline sync RFC and it seems one needs to just poll and compare flags with local cache. A little painful, was hoping there's something like the CalDAV protocol where you get fetch for changes given a sync uid.

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà Although I now see that there is still a way of minimizing traffic on servers that support the CONDSTORE extensions: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4549 

In essence I could perform a FETCH 1:* (FLAGS) (CHANGEDSINCE <cached-value> query. Does mailcore allow for such queries?

Comment: See `-syncMessagesWithFolder:requestKind:kids:modSeq:`. QRESYNC will probably be missing to detect deleted messages.

Comment: Cheers, that's fine as I only need to know if some flags changed.